# What is the way to upload the actual username from PFFacebookUtils to the Parse Cloud?

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

I have my [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions] like this:

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"user_about_me"];
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

if (!user) {
 NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
 } else if (user.isNew) {

 } else {
 NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
 } }];
```

The problem is that the method uploads an username similar to "St42o7PejDRh6scvMJylgOxGQ". What i want is to have the real username from Facebook uploaded, as well as the Facebook password and other relevant fields.

EDIT : With username i am specifically meaning First name, last name, and email if possible !

Comment: The `username` field has been removed in API v2. And getting their Facebook password – are you serious …?

Comment: Maybe i haven't explained myself clear enough. I wanna have the username upload to parse and not some weird FB ID.

Comment: Again: The actual `username` field is _not available_ via FB API any more. You can get at most their first name, last name and middle name/initial (if set).

Comment: yeah thats it ! With username i meant the first name and last name sorry !

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API uses OAuth as auth mechanism, so there's no way to get the username and password.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/v2.3
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you, but because Facebook removed this feature from their API you can't access it like you can for, let's say a PFUser 
example:

```
NSString *userName = [[PFUser user] username];
```

What you **CAN** do however is open up a `Facebook Graph API` request in order to retrieve this information like such:

1) First set the parameters of what you want to get from Facebook: (here i just did the FB id, the username, and the email)

```
NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setValue:@"id,name,email" forKey:@"fields"];
```

2) Just call the Facebook Graph API and request the information that you need like such:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Facebook Graph API user: %@", result);
        }
    }];
```

3) This is what you should get: (I have replaced personal information with generic pointers for security reasons)

```
2015-11-15 18:52:18.204 YOURAPPNAME[60800:18917239] Facebook Graph API user: {
    id = <the user id>;
    name = "Full User Facebook Name";
    email = "user@email.com";
}
```

Hopefully this will help you get what you are looking for! If its too late, at maybe this will help someone else in the future